# java - how to add image to mysql query browser?

Tags: mysql, jdbc, blob

I can't seem find a way how to add an image to a blob data type in mysql. Do I need to hard code it and then execute a statement? I am using MySQL Query Browser. view screenshot [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mQxcC.jpg)

Comment: Consider putting aside a few minutes to take a look at [some guidelines about asking questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). It's generally considered a good practice to show some efforts in terms of actual code when asking.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion sir and sorry for not following guidelines.